# similar to pandas.resample but in node.js [danfo.js]

Tags: node.js, time-series, pandas-resample, danfojs

I am new to **node.js** and I am looking for a way to **mimick the output of pandas.resample(‘3H’**, label=’right’, closed=’left’).max() working with timeseries, being able to obtain a dataframe-like structure with the maximum value that happened in blocks of 3 hours (1 value every 3 hours, the maximum one). I would be interested also in obtaining data with a granularity of 20 minutes and more granularities.

I am exploring dataframes in **danfo.js** https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/dataframe but I don't see anything that does the same functionality as resample.

Please could you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no npm package exists yet that provides such a feature.
I've done a simple implementation of my own code before.
[See this link.](https://gist.github.com/hillkim7/ff852d3a5d6810a582d62ef7a1140f37)